# Kafka stored avro records backward schema compatibility

Tags: avro, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

Question related to the Avro backward compatibility and rocksdb local stores:

let's assume I consume a  topic as a global table materialized into a rocksdb store. I can then do store.get(K) to retrieve V. Now, let's say I must redeploy my stream app keeping the same local store but with a new version of the Avro schema of K simply including a new optional field. Should I expect to still be able to retrieve from my local store the already persisted V under the first version of K if I now lookup with a K serialized using the new version of the Avro (given the new optional field is set to null)?

I was under the impression this should have worked but the lookup always return null. I can print the list of former K,V by iterating through the store and I can see the persisted K does look exactly like the one I am using when doing store.get(K). Although Avro is meant to be backward compatible, is it normal that we have to delete and recreate the store when changing the schema?

Comment: I suspect this can't work because the objects will be serialized with a different serialVersionUID.